# Some substitutions are more general than others (are). Which is better?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, be

"Some substitutions are more general than others".

or

"Some substitutions are more general than others **are**".

I am aware of the concept of using the verbs "to do" and "to be" at the end of a phrase for the purpose of succinctness, I really **am**. But the second variant seems a bit redundant to me.

Which version is better in the context of a (math) textbook?
What's the difference between them?

Comment: It's short and succinct as it is; why add another verb when it's meaningless (_are_ is the auxiliary required for predicate adjectives and has no meaning) and solves no problem (there's no ambiguity in the sentence)? With really short sentences one doesn't need much dressing.

Comment: I agree that there is no need in adding another "are". Is the second version (with "are" at the end) grammatically correct?

Comment: It's grammatical; it's just unnecessary, is all.

Comment: Thank you, @John. Please consider transferring you comments to an answer. I would accept it with great pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Using "are" at the end of the sentence helps convey the tense of the pronoun "others" when comparing it to "substitutions" in its present tense. In other words, without using "are" at the end of the sentence you open it up to other possible semantic interpretations.

For example, if you use the first sentenece, "Some substitutions are more general than others", it could mean some substitutions are, in their present state at this moment, more general than others used to be, will be in the future, or have been at some point in the past. By adding "are" at the end you specify that you are speaking in the present tense about the pronoun "others".

Most commonly people naturally assume the pronoun is being referred to in the present tense if the noun is stated in the present tense but, adding "are" to describe the state of the pronoun "other" removes any ambiguity.

If you are referring to something that is essentially a physical law, or is intrinsically true in any tense of the subject such as, "some fish are bigger than others". It is not wrong to use "are" in that case, just never necessary.

However, if the topic is something that has a more fluid dynamic to its comparability like, "These textbooks are heavier than my others," it is helpful to qualify the tense of "others" with "are" to specify exactly which group of textbooks the person is talking about. You could say "others were last year", "others from science class", "others are" (implying all of the textbooks you consider to be yours), or even "others will be" which still isn't entirely clear as it could mean tomorrow, next year, or for a different subject.

Long story short, adding "are" just helps add specificity if there is any room for assumption, and also "covers your rear" so people are less likely to misinterpret your meaning.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your effort but context matters. Could you please emphasize the part 'It is not wrong to use "are" in that case, just never necessary'?. You might want to put that paragraph at the beginning of your answer, for the rest of your explanation is concerned with more general case than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have rightly observed that the second varient is a bit heavy (though 'are' there is not redundant). If we can get at the intended effect in a short, crisp and straightforward manner, specially in scientific discourse, we would naturally  go for the same. Actually, when we avoid  verb, we use 'than' as a preposition and when we put a verb, 'than' works as a conjunction and demands an elliptical sentence.

Comment: So, the 2nd variant is 'heavy' but 'not redundant'. Could you elaborate on that a little bit? I really don't see the difference in *this* particular case.

Comment: After preposition ('than') an object will do. It is very much common is colloquial and day to day usage. When we think 'than' a conjunction we can use both a noun or pronoun in nominative case ( John/ I etc.)with or without verb. But without verb is extremely formal and avoided in written English. So we have the option either to nominative case and verb or only an objective case wise noun or pronoun. Since science let us know, driving home the truth is vital